# read_graph error with graphml data: : Graph index was too large, Invalid value

Tags: r, igraph, rcurl

I'm trying to read in the following URL (http://sdi.fish.govt.nz/sdi/mapserver.wfs?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=Annual%20distribution%20of%20Albacore%20tuna&VERSION=1.1.0) into R (3.2.2). From the website it looks to be in either gml or graphml format. I would like to convert it to a usable shapefile but i'm getting stuck at the import stage.

```
library(RCurl)
library(igraph)    
test_url <- 'http://sdi.fish.govt.nz/sdi/mapserver.wfs?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=Annual%20distribution%20of%20Albacore%20tuna&VERSION=1.1.0'
getURL(test_url)
# example of some of the substantial amount of output
# [1] "ï»¿<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><wfs:FeatureCollection xmlns:gml=\"http://www.opengis.net/gml\" xmlns:fish=\"http://www.fish.govt.nz/fish\" xmlns:gmlsf=\"http://www.opengis.net/gmlsf\"
read_graph(testURl, format='graphml')
# Error in .Call("R_igraph_read_graph_graphml", file, as.numeric(index),  : 
# At foreign-graphml.c:1350 : Graph index was too large, Invalid value
```

Is there a way round the graph index being to large or an alternate approach to reading the data in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL is neither in GraphML nor in GML format. It has a namespace named `gml`, but that refers to the [Geography Markup Language](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/gml), not the [Graph Markup Language](http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/) (GraphML) or the [Graph Modelling Language](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Graph_Modelling_Language) (also GML).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, didn't realise it was such a cluttered name space and was confusing myself.